# How do I database level contraints to my rails application long after I've migrated everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, constraints

1) I've created an entire Rails JSON API as my first project. It's fairly sizeable, and I put off database level constraints at the time. It's time to do it now.

I have 30+ or so migrations. For example

```
    class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :items do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.text :description

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

When I go in and edit

```
t.string :name
```

to be

```
t.string :name, null: false
```

and run a bundle exec db:reset db:migrate it doesn't work. What do I need to do to add db level constraints to my migrations files, and re migrate them?

2) Also, my 30+ migrations all have a "def change" and that's it. I believe somewhere a long time ago I saw something like def up, def down or something like that. It looks like it was used for rollbacks. Do I need to have "def down" for all of my migrations? Is that how I solve #1? Put "def down" in all of my 30 migrations, rollback the entire thing, then put in my db level constraints, and migrate the whole thing again?

Comment: 1) When you say "doesn't work", what exactly does that mean? What happens when you run the migrations?

Comment: 2) `up` and `down` predate `change`. Change was added later and works in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: you can write new migrations to make changes to the existing columns. In console:

```
rails g migration add_null_to_name
```

In the migration file:

```
class ChangeNumbericFieldInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :my_table, :name, :string, :null => false
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :my_table, :name, :string
end
```

Rinse and repeat for all the changes you need to make. Note that you can define them in the same migration file, but then if you had to rollback in the future it would roll back all of them.

Your second option is to roll everything back (or just start over), fix your migration methods and remigrate. This might be a cleaner approach, but that's not necessarily a good thing: it would also delete the existing data, if you have any.

I know I said you have two options, but you actually also have a third option, which is to to rely on model validations instead. These are more appropriate in most situations and can make testing much easier. Database validations are more reserved for complex scenarios where the database is used by other applications in addition to yours, and a few other edge cases.

As for your second question, every migration is a two-way street. When you migrate something, you should also be able to roll it back. In a lot of cases Rails can guess the reverse operation. For example, if you `add_column` in a migration, the opposite of that is obviously `remove_column` so you don't need to define it explicitly. But certain operations, such as `change_column` in the example above, don't have an obvious reverse. Rails can understand that *something* changed, but it can't tell what it changed *from*. So in those situations you need to explicitly define the `down` operation. In the case above, it's changing the column back to a state where it doesn't have a validation.

Comment: I feel like I Want to do option 2. I have no existing data that I care about. All the data I do care about exists in seeds.rb anyway. However, let say I put the db level validations in the original migration files. Such a null: false column change. Later down the road, when my DB is actually in use... I can just add a migration to remove it, if I needed to, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, you would also need to go back and retroactively change the existing data that does not fit that new constraint. For example, if you add a constraint that says name should be longer than five characters, you would need to go back and fix all names with five or fewer characters. There are ways to do that too, either as part of the migration or as explicit database queries.